# SSRS Button in App Embedded Report Sends to a SSRS Server Link

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have successfully embedded an SSRS report into my application and on the report I have a table with some data. I have grouped some columns and indicated in details group properties that it can be collapsible like so:
[image]

(If anyone is wondering the expression on the `month` is just doing this `=Left(MonthName(Fields!monthNumber.Value), 3)` and works as expected.
Preview result is something like this which in SSRS builder preview behaves as expected.

[image]

Now the problem is, when I go on and try to press the button to collapse or show some of the months in my live app, the report I am assuming tries to reload and instead the buttons send me to an SSRS link that is a completely irrelevant page to my webapp and the page looks something like this:

[image]

Get help button just sends me to a Microsoft site that is kind of useless.

I AM forced to use a rather old and meh IDE called "Alpha Anywhere" and I am not exactly sure if it is just the IDE quick. I don't think it should be, something credential-wise is probably going weird.
The report itself is configured to use a shared data source from SQL Server that is accessed using security credentials I created specifically for SSRS.
Basically everything is working fine, just the collapse buttons are acting unexpectedly.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I can't say I have ever experienced that behaviour; if you are being taken to a web page that *imples* you have an on click action on the text box. If it is the fault of development environment's that you are using then you I would suggest tagging that, to attract the attention of SMEs in that.

Comment: @Larnu I would, but I am not sure how I would tag "Alpha Anywhere" or "Alpha IDE" because it certainly is not a popular software because its really old (and I dislike it personally). There don't appear to be any tags for it in Stack Overflow